# Logrotate rotating one hour after log creation instead of on the hour

Tags: logrotate

I have the following logrotate config that I want to use to rotate a log hourly. It works but I noticed that instead of logrotate rotating on the hour (e.g. 13:00, 14:00), it seems to rotate an hour after the log was created. So the logfiles are all timestamped something like 13:15, 14:15 which matches the time the service that created the logfile was started.

Is there any way to make logrotate rotate on the hour?

```
/var/log/serial/*.log {
        su user user
        hourly
        dateext dateformat -%Y%m%d%H
        missingok
        compress
        compressoptions -9
        rotate 4
        notifempty
        nocreate
        postrotate
               sudo systemctl restart serial.service
        endscript
}
```

Comment: Are you running `logrotate` via cron? What is the schedule?

Comment: I'm not sure. Whatever is the default in Ubuntu 18.04 is what I'm using.

Comment: Are you using `anacron` on your Ubuntu system?